# missing ; before statement - AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I keep getting the above error for some reason. I've tried commenting out all of my other javascript, and it fixed nothing. Here's my code:

```
    function violation_change(){
        var vio = document.getElementById('violation').value;
        if(vio==''){
            document.getElementById('violation_report').innerHTML='This person has no current violations.';
            return;
        }
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("violation_report").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/addCall.php?violation="+vio+"&pro=<?php echo $_GET['pro']; ?>",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

EDIT: $_GET['pro'] is just a number. Forgot to mention it, sorry.

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['pro']`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: $_GET['pro'] is just a number that corresponds to the current property that the original programmer used. It's relevant to the SQL.

Comment: Well, a number shouldn't be an issue. I tried your code and got no syntax error, so the problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Is PHP actually executing your code? Or is the PHP just getting sent to the browser verbatim?

Comment: It might be elsewhere. The original programmer had a habit of not tying things up. I looked through it and nothing appeared to be wrong though.  Also, it's throwing the error when the page loads, before the function gets called.

Comment: Does this happen on any particular browser?

Comment: It happens in FF and Chrome. Haven't checked in IE, but I'm assuming it wont work. I'm sure it's an error on the old programmer's part if the problem isn't obvious.

Comment: If you put a number instead of `<?php echo $_GET['pro']; ?>` and get errors, then there's something going on in some other piece of code, and we'd have to see it. If you use a good code editor, that missing `;`  should light up like a christmas tree, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urlencode()` around the `$_GET['pro'];`:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/addCall.php?violation="+vio+"&pro=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['pro']); ?>",true);
```

EDIT:
Okay this will not do it still. You need to addslashes to all the speechmarks too:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/addCall.php?violation="+vio+"&pro=<?php echo addslashes(urlencode($_GET['pro'])); ?>",true);
```

Comment: Did not work. $_GET['pro'] is just a number (which I forgot to specify earlier).